# How to invoke a subprocess with an additional file-descriptor?

Tags: python, unix

I'm writing a Python-wrapper over a program, that can only output things into files -- specified by filename:

```
program -o filename
```

Because my wrapper needs to read/process these data *while the program is still running*, I want to give it the "name" of a file-descriptor:

```
program -o /dev/fd/FD
```

Sometimes it also makes utterings to `stderr` and `stdout` -- which prevents me from simply using `/dev/stderr` or `/dev/stdout`.

I don't have to use `subprocess.Popen`, but that seems the most flexible. How can I:

1. Open the pipe in my wrapper.
2. Invoke the wrapped program passing it the descriptor of the child's end of the pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a fifo in the file system. The called program will open the file and write but you'll get it on the other side of the pipe.

```
import os
import subprocess as subp
import uuid

fn = "/tmp/myfifo-" + uuid.uuid4().hex
try:
    os.mkfifo(fn)
    p = subp.Popen(['./program', '-o', fn])
    for line in open(fn):
        print('got:', line.strip())
    print('done')
finally:
    if os.path.exists(fn):
        os.remove(fn)
```